# Error while using SOAP API of cybersource

Tags: payment-gateway, soapui

I am trying to use SOAP based Cybersource payment gateway service. Currently I am trying to use Test environment that Cybersource provides for testing sample test credit card transactions.

1. Created a project in SOAP UI using the WSDL : https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.80.wsdl
2. SOAP UI generated the test method runTransaction.
3. I copied the same SOAP message provided in Cybersource documentation in to SOAP UI as the SOAP message, which I have given below.
4. When I send this request, I am getting the following error:

If anyone has worked on this before or faced this issue, please provide pointers. Thanks!

Ram

**Response:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.0">
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Element ():requestMessage not supported.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**SOAP Message:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">TQc3LSaKfGWfgccqYX3mGhXfhBqnjyVzf5g1aeP3mDPFoMlFDfyKrKnhrqt2bHm3QeXTF1l+Aku/v4sFwIctcGtMNkwZDTMjxAAvuqnmedTa/Q9YxCS8OlhdYWOpJOAQGdyvT6bb0496RuzWN07kQZsPExY8BQDBpll6jpLvdQ6qbBK7MFSnO/2YbFaAaZIaFd+EGqePJXN/mDVp4/eYM8WgyUUN/IqsqeGuq3ZsebdB5dMXWX4CS7+/iwXAhy1wa0w2TBkNMyPEAC+6qeZ51Nr9D1jEJLw6WF1hY6kk4BAZ3K9PptvTj3pG7NY3TuRBmw8TFjwFAMGmWXqOku91Dg==</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.80">
         <urn:merchantID>username</urn:merchantID>
         <urn:merchantReferenceCode>MRC-123</urn:merchantReferenceCode>
         <urn:billTo>
            <urn:firstName>John</urn:firstName>
            <urn:lastName>Doe</urn:lastName>
            <urn:street1>1295 Charleston Road</urn:street1>
            <urn:city>Mountain View</urn:city>
            <urn:state>CA</urn:state>
            <urn:postalCode>94043</urn:postalCode>
            <urn:country>US</urn:country>
            <urn:email>null@cybersource.com</urn:email>
         </urn:billTo>
         <urn:item id="0">
            <urn:unitPrice>5.00</urn:unitPrice>
            <urn:quantity>1</urn:quantity>
         </urn:item>
         <urn:item id="1">
            <urn:unitPrice>10.00</urn:unitPrice>
            <urn:quantity>2</urn:quantity>
         </urn:item>
         <urn:purchaseTotals>
            <urn:currency>USD</urn:currency>
         </urn:purchaseTotals>
         <urn:card>
            <urn:accountNumber>4111111111111111</urn:accountNumber>
            <urn:expirationMonth>11</urn:expirationMonth>
            <urn:expirationYear>2020</urn:expirationYear>
         </urn:card>
         <urn:ccAuthService run="true"/>
      </urn:requestMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: The same issue i am also facing, did u get any solution for this?

Comment: the header was very useful ! thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem.  The url for the wsse namespace has an extra ' ' (space) that shouldn't be in there on the 3rd line of your XML.  The URL should be: 

http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd 

with no space preceding the /wss/  ...docs.oasis-open.org/ wss/...

Answer (score 1):

Check the time on the server. I recently ran into the exact same issue and turned out the server time was off by 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same message.

Unfortunately it's not conclusive what the exact error might be, but I found that mine was due to a malformed Security header. (Which is not very intuitive from the error message.)

I don't see anything immediately wrong with your Security header, but you might double check your namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add it as Service Reference or Web Reference, It should be Added as Web Reference. Also you need  to install WSE 3.0 Service from Microsoft to get the `TransactionProcessorWse`